# Change checkbox background without labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want to custom my checkbox. I see this method of custom all the time :

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

.my_label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 13px; 
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    line-height:18px;
}

.my_label:before {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    background-image: url("images/checkbox-bg.gif");
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + .my_label:before {
    background: url("images/checkbox-checked-bg.gif");
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

It's ok when we have this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox"> <label for="my_checkbox" class="my_label">
```

But atm in my code I need to have NO label. Just 1 checkbox that depends on nothing. 
Just something like that :

```
<input class="my_checkbox_class" id="my_checkbox_id" onclick="my_function()">
```

Any idea please?
I'm sure it's pretty simple, I'm sorry by advance..

Thanks.

Comment: Are you comfortable using Javascript or jQuery for this? Am asking because you have tagged this question with Javascript/jQuery, so am thinking that you won't mind an answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using a little bit of Javacript / jQuery, then you could add a `label` at runtime  and the same CSS would apply. You also *don't* need `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements.

For example, on document ready find all checkboxes and then add a label after each of them. Remember, to assign checkbox `id` to the label's `for` attribute. Something like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    var $lbl = $("<label>");
    $lbl.attr("for", this.id);
    $(this).after($lbl);
});
```

**Note:** *The benefit of this approach is that you can re-use your existing CSS. No need to change anything. I suppose this is what you wanted in your question.*

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pdczc9vo/2/***

***Snippet:***

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    var $lbl = $("<label>");
    $lbl.attr("for", this.id);
    $(this).after($lbl);
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px; height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0px 8px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background-color: #dd6666;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" /> 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" /> 
<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-styles to the checkbox itself, and rather than hide the box, just set its width to 0:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    width:0px;
    margin-right:25px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    background-color:#ccc;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
    background-color:red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```